# Seamless background of subfigure bodies, but not captions

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, color, subfloats

I have 3 sub-figures:

```
\begin{figure}
    \subfloat[Apple]{
        \includegraphics{apple}
    }
    \subfloat[Orange]{
        \includegraphics{orange}
    }
    \subfloat[Cherry]{
        \includegraphics{cherry}
    }
\end{figure}
```

I want the background behind the row of images to be a solid black rectangle, with no gaps between the images. How can I achieve this?

I have used `colorbox` around the separate images, but this leaves gaps between them. If I wrap the whole thing in a `colorbox` then the captions also have the background color, which I do not want.

I have also tried putting a `tikz` node in the top left and bottom right, but using `overlay` puts a black box on top of the images, not below them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the spaces from your code:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig,xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \subfloat[Apple]{%<---
        \colorbox{red}{\includegraphics{apple}}%<...
    }
    \subfloat[Orange]{%<---
        \colorbox{red}{\includegraphics{orange}}%<---
    }
    \subfloat[Cherry]{%<---
        \colorbox{red}{\includegraphics{cherry}}%
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 This is a good suggestion. I missed a key point in my question---the captions come too close to each other if I take such an approach. Perhaps I can tweak the caption width.... I didn't think of that last night.

Comment: \captionsetup{margin=1ex}. You can also enlarge the borders of the colorbox by changing \fboxsep.

Answer (score 3):

This one does not use minipages, makebox or vphantom at all:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption,xcolor}

%\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin=5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin=5pt}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox
    {A long caption about cherries that spans two lines}
    [0.32\linewidth]
    {\colorbox{black}{
      {\color{red}\rule{0.3\linewidth}{90pt}}
      }
    }
  \subcaptionbox
    {A long caption about oranges that spans two lines}
    [0.32\linewidth]
    {\colorbox{black}{
      {\color{orange}\rule{0.3\linewidth}{90pt}}
      }
    }
  \subcaptionbox
    {A long caption about apples that spans two lines}
    [0.32\linewidth]
    {\colorbox{black}{
      {\color{green}\rule{0.3\linewidth}{90pt}}
      }
    }

  \caption{Some fruits, with a black background to help with contrast.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Minipages and `captionsetup` to the rescue

@Ulrike Fischer's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2661/seamless-background-of-subfigure-bodies-but-not-captions/2675#2675) is a good start. By placing the sub-figures exactly next to each-other you can get each `colorbox` to touch the next one.

This, however, results in captions which may be too close to each other. To address this, I've wrapped each `subfloat` in a `minipage` and added `\captionsetup{width=0.95\textwidth}` to constrain the width of the sub-captions. It's also important to be sure that the contents of each `colorbox` is fully as wide as the space needed, so I've used yet another `minipage`.

**For example:**

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.32\linewidth}
        \captionsetup{width=0.95\textwidth}
        \subfloat[A long caption about cherries that spans two lines]{
            \colorbox{black}{
                \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
                    \centering
                    {\color{red}\rule{0.8\textwidth}{90pt}}
                \end{minipage}
            }
        }
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.32\linewidth}
        \captionsetup{width=0.95\textwidth}
        \subfloat[A long caption about oranges that spans two lines]{
            \colorbox{black}{
                \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
                    \centering
                    {\color{orange}\rule{0.8\textwidth}{90pt}}
                \end{minipage}
            }
        }
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.32\linewidth}
        \captionsetup{width=0.95\textwidth}
        \subfloat[A long caption about apples that spans two lines]{
            \colorbox{black}{
                \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
                    \centering
                    {\color{green}\rule{0.8\textwidth}{90pt}}
                \end{minipage}
            }
        }
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Some fruits, with a black background to help with contrast.}
\end{figure}
```

**Results in:**

[image]

**Improve this!**

I tend to overuse minipages. Please post a better answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I've never found a use for minipages. I'm sure one exists, but in most cases, a `\parbox` works just as well. For example, here, you seem to be using `minipage` just to constrain the width of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I can only offer a bit of a hack with tikz

The background library fits the whole figure including captions. By adding a white line on the bottom of the background rectangle the captions appear again.

A much easier solution is probably not to use the \subfloat command at all and to arrange the pictures in tikz nodes and then simply use the fit-library (or again the background library) to draw the rectangle around the nodes. In this approach caption could be added with the \captionof command from the caption or the capt-of package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\tikzset{background rectangle/.style={fill=black},
background bottom/.style={draw=white,line width=8ex}}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[framed,tight background,show background bottom,outer frame xsep=4pt]
 \node {
    \subfloat[Apple]{
        {\color{red}
        \rule{0.3\textwidth}{90pt}}
    }
    \subfloat[Orange]{%
        {\color{orange}\rule{0.3\textwidth}{90pt}}
    }
    \subfloat[Cherry]{%
        {\color{red!90!green}%
        \rule{0.3\textwidth}{90pt}}
    }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you are really using a lot of minipages. As I already said in my comment I would use \captionsetup{margin=...}. You can also put a black rule between the floats. (I'm using the makebox to get a bit overhang, this will close small gaps due to pixel rounding).

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig,xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}\captionsetup{margin=2ex}\fboxsep=1ex
   \subfloat[A long caption about apples that spans two lines]{%
        \colorbox{black}{{\color{red}\rule{0.3\linewidth}{90pt}}}%<...
    }%
   \makebox[1cm]{\colorbox{black}{\vphantom{\rule{0.3\linewidth}{90pt}}\hspace{1cm}}}%
  \subfloat[A long caption about apples that spans two lines]{%
        \colorbox{black}{{\color{orange}\rule{0.3\linewidth}{90pt}}}%<---
    }
    \subfloat[Cherry]{%<---
        \colorbox{black}{{\color{green}\rule{0.3\linewidth}{90pt}}}%
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```